# Who won the FIDE Chess Clock Contract Bidding?

Tags: fide, chess-clocks

It should have been announced on September 23. But still, nothing on the FIDE website has appeared. Does anyone know who won in all 3 categories?

Comment: If they dont require their own clocks why would anyone buy an official FIDE one?  If they do require them then they will lose lots of tournament entries not encourage more players to play.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FIDE website](https://fide.com/news/113):

> FIDE is pleased to announce that, in compliance with the published
> Bidding Procedure, it completed the scoring of offers submitted for
> the chess clock contract tender. **The winners have been determined,**
> **conditional on the manufacturers' signing binding contracts with FIDE**.

So, FIDE have chosen a winner but the winners have not yet signed a binding contract.
Presumably the contract is still being negotiated.

Note this earlier link from August 2019 - https://old.fide.com/images/stories/NEWS_2019/FIDE_News/20190805-FIDE-Bidding_procedure-ChessClocks.pdf - defining the bidding process giving the following schedule:

> **9. Bidding Timeline**
>
> 9.1 Bidding starts August 05, 2019.
> 9.2 End of inquiry period for bidders August 15, 2019.
> 9.3 FIDE publishes responses August 23, 2019.
> 9.4 Deadline for bidders to submit bids September 10, 2019.
> 9.5 FIDE announces the winner(s) September 23, 2019.
> 9.6 **Deadline for winner(s) to sign a contract September 30, 2019**.
> 9.7 **Contract(s) shall come into force October 01, 2019**.
> 9.8 Contract(s) effective through September 30, 2022.

According to the schedule published in August it was planned that contracts would have been signed and come into effect by now. Perhaps over optimistic on the part of FIDE.

Assuming that contracts have been signed and [FIDE are keeping it secret or are too lazy](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/who-won-the-fide-chess-clock-contract-bidding) to update their website would be very foolish. For a start the winners would almost certainly publish the fact widely.